# chart line with multi part

Tags: c#, charts

I want line chart with multi part like this

[image]

But with this code

```
chartMain.Series["chart"].ChartType = SeriesChartType.Line;
chartMain.Series["chart"].Points.AddXY(10, 100);
chartMain.Series["chart"].Points.AddXY(20, 100);

chartMain.Series["chart"].Points.AddXY(23, 100);
chartMain.Series["chart"].Points.AddXY(25, 100);

chartMain.Series["chart"].Points.AddXY(30, 100);
chartMain.Series["chart"].Points.AddXY(36, 100);
```

Show it

[image: #]

Please help me to draw line chart with multi parts

Comment: What charting tool are you using? It isn't clear

Comment: MSChart will always connect all datapoints in a series. Either go for multiple series, or, recommended, insert transparent points ie make every 2nd point transparent!

Comment: with this code can hidden gap location chartMain.Series["chart"].Points.AddXY(23, double.NaN);